# ImportError when importing scanpy on a Jupyter notebook with VS Code

Tags: python, jupyter

When setting the environment of my notebook I need to import scanpy at the very beginning of my file with the usual commands:

First in VS code terminal:

```
pip install scanpy
```

And then in my first cell:

```
import scanpy as sc
```

But then, when i run the cell alone i get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'colormaps' from 'matplotlib' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py)

I don't understand where this 'name error' can come from :/ Is there something I can do?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Update scanpy. It is Released: Oct 31, 2023

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; I originally used following in Jupyter:
!pip install scanpy

After receiving the error, uninstalled scanpy, using:
!python -m pip uninstall scanpy --yes

And restarted the computer and installed scanpy using cmd window:
pip3 install scanpy

Then opened Jupyter, restarted Kernel, and now I can import scanpy with no errors.

Comment: In what you originally used, you were trying outdated commands. You should have originally used `%pip install scanpy`. The magic variations of the install commands were added in 2019 to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. See more about the magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). More can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77677226/jupyterlab-not-detecting-installed-module-textract-and-doc2text#comment136942483_77677226).